# Passing dynamic parameters to a function (NOT arguments) in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

just in case you want to know the context:

I have a single 'contact' database table (mysql) for many types of contacts, what I want to achieve is to pass the attributes to a query depending on the contact type.
(NOTE: this code contains some Laravel Eloquent syntax)

```
$attributes=ContactAttributes::where('type',$contact->type_id)->first()->attributes;
//array of attribute names

call_user_func_array($contact->lists(),$attributes);
//try to call lists with attribute names which will be translated to a SQL query SELECT ... FROM 'contacts'
```

But is seems that `call_user_func_array` is actually calling lists() function without any parameters which returns an error. all I want to do is to actually call lists function with the attributes as parameters and not arguments like so `lists($attributes[0],$attributes[1],$attributes[2],...)`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call a method using an object, you should specify both the object and the method like so:

```
call_user_func_array( array( $contact, 'lists' ), $attributes);
```

There are more examples in [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Comment: Following the example you provided It worked flawlessly.
however I found another Laravel function that accepts array as parameter so I no longer need to pass dynamic parameters.
So I chose it as the best answer relative to the question asked.

If any of you interested I used eloquent select function to solve this.
http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_select